# How to choose middle element of the array as the pivot in quicksort?

Tags: python, quicksort

I have to implement quicksort in python. I have implemented the following code.

```
def quickSort(array, p, r):
    
    if p < r:
        q = partition(array, p, r)
        quickSort(array, p, q- 1)
        quickSort(array, q + 1, r)
        
def partition(array, p, r):
    
    x = array[r]
    i = p - 1        
    
    for j in range(p, r):
        if array[j] <= x:
            i = i+1
            array[i], array[j] = array[j], array[i]
    
    array[i+1], array[r] = array[r], array[i+1]

    return (i+1)


array =  [7, 2, 5, 7, 2, 0, 5, 3, 6, 0, 3, 3, 5, 9, 0, 6]
print(f"A: {array}")
n = len(array)
quickSort(array, 0, n-1)
print(f"sorted A: {array}")
```

I have to choose middle index of the array as pivot to check the best case time complexity, but when I input x = array[r//2] for selecting the middle, I am getting incorrect output.
For the array mentioned above I am getting the output
A: [0, 0, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 0, 6, 6, 7, 5, 5, 5, 9, 7]
When I use the last element as the pivot i.e. x = array[r] I am getting correct output.

Any clue as to how to select the middle element of array[8] as the pivot?

Comment: @KellyBundy I consider this one under "not reproducible or typo", as someone looking for `tag:python` or `tag:quicksort` will not likely to have this exact bug in their code.

Comment: @Amadan Yes I understand my silly m new but mistake I am new. But the output for (p+r)//2 is [0, 0, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 0, 6, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7, 9]

Comment: That is because `range(p, r)` naturally avoids `r`; if your pivot is not `r`, you would have to actively avoid it by using `range(p, r+1)` and testing if `j` is not the pivot index.

Comment: @Amadan I don't see what that has to do with it.

Comment: for j in range(p,r+1):

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to swap it with array[r] and continue as normal:

```
def partition(array, p, r):
    array[(p+r)//2], array[r] = array[r], array[(p+r)//2]
    x = array[r]
    // ...
```